# PHP Session doesn't work in all directories

Tags: php, session

I have a problem, I have a website where you can log in.

There are one log in for administration and one website, they both work with same MySQL table.

When I log in on front page, sessions are available on every subsite for example `www.example.com` and `www.example.com/main` or `www.example.com/main?func=delete`, sessions are all *ok*.

But when I want to access them via ajax in my file which is in subfolder `www.example.com/libs/ajax/addBox.php`, they are *not available* there.

Administration works the same, only for folder `/admin/` but I have to log in again (it's ok for me) but not that it doesn't work in ajax and all others.

This is my `print_r()` of my `$_SESSION` and `session_get_cookie_params()` in:

**main_page (after login)**

```
Array
(
    [lifetime] => 5184000
    [path] => /
    [domain] => http://new.visitandexplore.eu/
    [secure] => 
    [httponly] => 1
)

Array
(
    [skup] => 3
    [zobrazHlaska] => 1
    [hlaska] => Úspešne prihlásený
    [ID] => 1
    [login] => tonoslav
    [admin] => 1
)
```

**Administration**

```
Array
(
    [lifetime] => 5184000
    [path] => /admin/
    [domain] => http://new.visitandexplore.eu/
    [secure] => 
    [httponly] => 1
)

Array
(
    [skup] => 3
    [kam] => /admin/?sub=docs
    [zobrazHlaska] => 1
    [hlaska] => Úspešne prihlásený
    [ID] => 1
    [login] => tonoslav
    [admin] => 1
)
```

**But /libs/ajax/ folder**

```
Array
(
    [lifetime] => 5184000
    [path] => /
    [domain] => http://new.visitandexplore.eu/
    [secure] => 
    [httponly] => 1
)

Array
(
    [skup] => 0
    [lat] => 48.130693199999996
    [long] => 17.0959508
    [gpos] => 1
)
```

`session_start()` is executed at the top of website.

Comment: Is `session_start()` included in the individual ajax files?

Comment: Define *top of the website*. It could very well be part of a template file that, as @jeroen suggests, is not actually being run for the standalone scripts accessed by AJAX.

Comment: Include `var_dump($_SESSION);` inside your (PHP) Ajax files.

Comment: it is on the same top as in frontpage or in administration, it's called by main class which is also in ajax @jeroen

Comment: @Fred-ii- I don't understand why, `print_r` is enough

Comment: Either/or. It's up to you. I like using both myself.

Comment: @Tonoslav I think var_dump gives more information. but Fred's right, it's up to you.